# Code port in window 8 issue,

Tags: window, unity-game-engine

I am new in unity development and I am an facing issue to make a neutral package for window 8.

I have unity code I have compiled successfully for iPhone. But when I am compiling it for windows 8, it is showing problems and I am not able to make neutral package for window 8.

The error given is:

```
SEHException was unhandled by user code
```

Comment: Welcome! I would suggest you to try to add some more details to your question like samples of the error messages you are getting. It will help others understand your problem better.

Comment: @veducm When in unity in build setting in platform I select window store apps ,it builds successfully but when i compile code it produces exceptions "SEHException was unhandled by user code".

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: @LexLi you might not know that we also use unity for compilation of code that we can port in different platform

Comment: No matter which platform you target, you should use unity3d tag.